# Rotating Images Like UIPicker VIew

Tags: iphone

HI, I am new to iPhone especially the Graphics part, I want to develop a Image Rotators just like the UIPickerView. but with my own custom design, It will look like something like the Casino Slot Machine, Can anybody guide me to some resources to do the Task in hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIPickerView allows for custom images to be used in the delegate. You can create your own  custom UIView and add an image to it. Look at the documentation.

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view

Answer (score 1):

To be able to rotate views in general you should take a look at transforms, here is a guide to transforms in the apple s ite http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html